# SSIS package with no found connection

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS project which used to run correctly. But opening it this time, I was really surprised with this error message showing:

> "Error loading the name_package. The connection "" is not found !!! (It does not even give the connection's name). This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found"

When I run the project it runs correctly but at the opening I have this error each time. I can't understand if it's OK or not. But this error is completely new!

I'm working with two different connection managers. I tried to create new ones and recompile. When closing and then reopening the project I get the same error once more.

What would cause this error and do I need to fix it?

Comment: How are you opening the package? With BIDS or using dtexec?  It sounds like BIDS. Also, has anything changed? Packages don't generally just stop working like this without an outside influence.

Comment: I'm opening it with BIDS. I may have renamed the connection manager once, then just reterned it to the old one. Normally, it's always the same connection manager but just with a different name. But that doesn't sound to be the cause of the errror.

Comment: Is there anything hiding in the XML code? I've had BIDS hold onto connection string data but not necessarily display them (after a nasty server failure when a package was half developed). Go to `View>Code` in the menu bar and search for "connection". and delete any odd looking lines!

Comment: I see that you tried recreating them but I'm guessing you did that using the same names. If you haven't already tried it, I'd recreate the connections under completely new names then reassigning the connections in the tasks within the package to the new connection, deleting the old connections.